# Why is PDO fetchColumn() not working here

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to count the number of rows returned by a query, and I'm doing like this:

```
$what = 'Norman';
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select names as names from names where names = :what');
$stmt->bindParam('what', $what);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

echo 'Rows found '.$rows;

$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{  
    echo $row['names'] . "<br>";
}
```

But I keep getting nothing at all. Just blank. Whats the right way to do this?

Comment: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: And yes, this fetchColumn() looks quite inconsistent here.

Comment: Do you receive any output for `'Rows found '.$rows;`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Actually, I just realized fetchColumn() was returning a name. I was expecting it to return a number (number of rows in the select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the number of rows returned use [`rowCount`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

```
// ...
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();

echo 'Rows found '.$rows;
// ...
```

Comment: I thought this does not work with mysql, but it's actually returning the number of rows in the table. I've read all over that rowCount() does not work with selects {Amazed}.

Comment: @Norman It does not work on some database systems. It does not list the working ones.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you are using improper functions here.

```
$what = 'Norman';
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select names from names where names = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($what));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); // it will actually return all the rows

echo 'Rows found '.count($rows);

foreach ($rows as $row)
{  
    echo $row['names'] . "<br>";
}
```

or you can make it even neater, by getting 1d array instead of 2d

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0); 

echo 'Rows found '.count($rows);

foreach ($rows as $name)
{  
    echo $name . "<br>";
}
```

But you have to check for PDO errors first