# Outputting a select count(name) value in php pdo with mySql

Tags: php, pdo

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select count(names) as names from names where names = :name');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

How do I output the value of names when doing a `select count()` using PDO without having to use a while loop or something similar?

I need the count value of names (1, 3 or 5 or whatever it is).

Comment: A a somewhat funny related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233323/why-is-pdo-fetchcolumn-not-working-here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

[fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

Comment: `execute` returns boolean. This will trigger `Call to a member on a non-object` error.

Answer (score 1):

The `select count(..) from ..`-Statement always only outputs this column (the count of rows), so you cannot access the names. You will have to execute a statement only for getting the names, OR you can actually output the name by yourself, because you already have it in `$name` ;)

Comment: I only need the count. Not the name.