# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchColumn()

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I'm trying  to get the count result returned from an sql query

```
require_once("inc/db_const.php");
$date=$_GET['date_rdv']; 
$mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
   echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
   exit();
}
$query_check="SELECT count(*) FROM planning_cl WHERE date_plannig = ?";
$statement_check = $mysqli->prepare($query_check);
$statement_check->bind_param('s',$date);
$statement_check->execute();
$rdv_verif=$statement_check->fetchColumn();
echo $rdv_verif;
```

but it shows me this error

```
r: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchColumn()
```

can any one give me any solution to solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is PDO fetchColumn() not working here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233323/why-is-pdo-fetchcolumn-not-working-here)

Comment: Well, yes, `mysql_stmt` indeed does not have a method called `fetchColumn`, period. That's not how mysqli works. Please RTFM to see examples of how mysqli is actually used: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: First you are not using pdo in your sample so you should remove that tag from your question. `mysqli` is the correct tag. Indeed I also find the `fetch_column` is missing from my mysqli version (Mariadb 10.6.4; mysqlnd 7.4.25). The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-column) is clear that this works from 8.1.0 only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no `mysqli_stmt::fetchColumn()` in MySQLi see[**Documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) This is a **PDO**
method.

For MySQLi use [**mysqli_stmt_num_rows ( )**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

```
$rdv_verif=$statement_check->mysqli_stmt_num_rows();
echo $rdv_verif;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong because this function will always return 1 for the query selecting `count(*)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `fetchColumn` method in mysqli, this method belongs to **another driver**, PDO.

but you can easily simulate it with `mysqli_fetch_row()[0]`:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM planning_cl WHERE date_plannig = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$date);
$stmt->execute();
$rdv_verif = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];
echo $rdv_verif;
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `$statement_check->fetch();`

```
require_once("inc/db_const.php");
$date=$_GET['date_rdv']; 
$mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
   echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
   exit();
}
$query_check="SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM planning_cl WHERE date_plannig = ?";
$statement_check = $mysqli->prepare($query_check);
$statement_check->bind_param('s',$date);
$statement_check->execute();
$line=$statement_check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rdv_verif = $line['cnt']
echo $rdv_verif;
```

Answer (score -2):

As seen in a similar question:

> [Why is PDO fetchColumn() not working here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233323/why-is-pdo-fetchcolumn-not-working-here)

---

If you want to get the number of rows returned use [`rowCount`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

```
// ...
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();

echo 'Rows found '.$rows;
// ...
```

---

Which is the most appropriate way of getting the number of rows that you need, so in your case:

```
$rdv_verif=$statement_check->rowCount();
```